# java Regular Expression to find exact word with special characters

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

I need to search `"$SE"` keyword for following sentences.

```
$SEBGI is there
there is $SE.
there is SE again
```

The output should be as below:

```
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

I have following regular expression.

```
String patternStr =  "(?i)\\b"+Pattern.quote("$SE")+"\\b";
```

But it returns `FALSE` for all the sentences.

Please help.

Comment: show your code, or else, we can't see what you're doing wrong. Also, you're requirements aren't clear enough. Should `ab$SE foo` be `true` or `false` ?

Comment: Please define exactly what you want to consider as a word boundary. The built-in `\b` only works for pure alphanumeric "words".

Comment: Could there ever be a non-alphanumeric character at the *end* of your "word"s (like `$SE$`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need word boundaries for this one.

I think the simplest solution is to use a sequence of non-word, "$SE" and non-word again.

For instance:

```
String first = "$SEBGI is there";
String second = "there is $SE.";
String third = "there is SE again";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W\\$SE\\W", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(first);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
matcher = pattern.matcher(second);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
matcher = pattern.matcher(third);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

Output:

```
false
true
false
```

Notes:

- I haven't used `Pattern.quote` since it's only one "problematic" character (*$*) so I just escaped it.
- I haven't used look-behinds or look-aheads as they are not really needed in this case.
- I haven't used grouping as you are not attempting to retrieve anything, only to check if the `String` contains a match of the `Pattern`.
- I have used the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag as you seem to require it (see your `(?i)` flag - same thing).

Comment: Thanks Mena it worked for this case. I have updated my question and added details. Can you please review and guide me.

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani this is **not** how SO works. Your new question looks ok, but you cannot change the original question radically and expect the people who answered it to just update their answers as well. I think you should roll back to your previous question, have it closed (or mark it as "answered") if necessary, and ask a new one, so everybody gets a chance to answer that new one fairly and clearly.

Comment: Ok i have marked your it as answer and will create new question

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String example = "the charseq test";
String pattern = "(?i).*(^|\\s)" + Pattern.quote("charseq") + "($|\\s).*";
boolean matches = example.matches(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use 4 separate expressions:

```
boolean str_beg = Pattern.matches("^\\$SE\\s", <input_str>);
boolean str_mid = Pattern.matches("\\s\\$SE\\s", <input_str>);
boolean str_end = Pattern.matches("\\s\\$SE$", <input_str>);
boolean str_all = Pattern.matches("^\\$SE$", <input_str>);
boolean matches = str_beg || str_mid || str_end || str_all;
```